# Material UI Palette custom color with ThemeProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to apply a custom color to a Button using createMuiTheme and ThemeProvider, and it works when using palette primary and secondary, but when i try to use any other, like "info", it doesnt work:

[image: code]

Anyone know what im doing wrong or any other way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primary and secondary attributes are the only ones recognized in palette object.

Comment: why? in the documentation they say "You may override the default palette values by including a palette object as part of your theme. If any of the:

    palette.primary
    palette.secondary
    palette.error
    palette.warning
    palette.info
    palette.success

palette color objects are provided, they will replace the defaults."

Comment: Anyway, ill just set the color with inline style instead.

Comment: Did you resolved it ? Thank you for marking my answer

Comment: Yeah, you are right it seems like it only recognizes those two attributes for some reason, but in v5 it recognizes the other attributes aswell. I resolved it by just styling inline.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a custom variant.
Creating a custom variant is supported in the latest version(Above v5) of material-UI.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'twitter' },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#00acee',
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: "#007cad",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: 'facebook' },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#3b5998',
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: "#314c85",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});

export default theme
```

UI

```
<Grid item>
    <Button variant="facebook" startIcon={<FacebookIcon />}>Facebook</Button>
</Grid>
<Grid item>
    <Button variant="twitter" startIcon={<TwitterIcon />}>Twitter</Button>
</Grid>
```

Here is the link that will help

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15573
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15573#issuecomment-724114107

Comment: thanks. I tried updating to v5, and it worked. The only downside is it broke everything else. Like now all my Menu/Select dropdown items are all on the same row and stuff... so i guess this isnt an option for now.

Comment: are you looking for an existing project? I don't suggest this solution existing project.
You might go with global CSS.

Comment: I just went with an inline style to change the color